# Suppose the EPA has established a limit of $5\%$ 2-buthoxyethanol in all consumer products. What is the probability that a bottle exceeds this limits?

Tags: probability, statistics

> The mean percent of $2$-Butoxyethanol in Rain-X Cleaner is $3$. Suppose the distribution is approximately normal and the standard deviation is $1\%$, and a random bottle of Rain-X Glass Cleaner is selected.
>   a. What is the probability that the percentage of $2$-butoxyethanol is less than $2.5$?
>   b. What is the probability that the  percentage of $2$-butoxyethanol is between $2.2$ and $3.5$?
>   c. Suppose the EPA has established a limit of $5\%$ 2-buthoxyethanol in all consumer products. What is the probability that a bottle exceeds this limits?

I'm having difficulty understand c) as well if anyone can describe to me when you would use cumulative probability. That would be much appreciated.

---

This is what I have come up with

c.
$P(X≤b)= 0.05$
$P((X-3)/1 ≤ (b-3)/1) = 0.05$
$P(X ≤ (b-9)/1) = 0.05$
($b-9)/1 = -1.64$
$b-9 = -1.64$
$b = 7.36$

Comment: What progress have you made so far? Please indicate what you have done/tried and where you are stuck. This help people better tailor their answer to your background and situation. It also shows that you are interested in the question and don't just want people to do your homework for you - Math.SE is not a homework site.

Comment: To expand on what c) is asking - If the bottle has 5% or more then its bad and should be banned. So this would be cumulative. Basically you want to use cumulative probability if you are interested in a range of values as opposed to a single value. If you are looking at normal distributions you will always be looking at a range and hence be doing cumulative probability.

Comment: This is what i have come up with
P(X≤b)= 0.05
P(X-3/1 ≤ b-3/1) = 0.05
P(X ≤ b-9/1) = 0.05
b-9/1 = -1.64
b-9 = -1.64
b = 7.36

Comment: We ask that you include your work _in the post_, not as a comment. Also, please use proper formatting. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Lastly, label which part you are answering.

Comment: Consider giving a respondent a [check mark](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Ian Miller, if you would not mind. Could you give me an example of a probability that is not cumulative?

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this in chunks. If the distribution is normal, that means that the probability density function (PDF) is:
$$f(x;\mu,\sigma)= A e^{\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma ^2}}$$
The mean and standard deviation are $\mu$ and $\sigma$ respectively. The amplitude A usually has a specific value but since x is bounded, $0<x<1$, then A has the normalizing condition that:
$$A= \frac{1}{\int _0^1e^{\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma ^2}}dx} $$
The probability between two values is then:
$$P(a<x<b)= \int_a^bf(x;\mu,\sigma) dx$$
Therefore, for part c, to be greater than 5%:
$$P(x>0.05)= \frac{\int _{0.05}^1e^{\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma ^2}}dx}{\int _0^1e^{\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma ^2}}dx}$$
The integral is for you to work out, and just to be clear, since I did everything with respect to decimals $\mu= 0.03$ and $\sigma= 0.01$.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, for part c), it says that the limit is $.05$ and it asks for the chance that a bottle *exceeds* this limit. Hence the event of interest is
$$\{X> .05\}$$
and so the probability of interest is
$$P(X> .05) = 1-P(X\leq .05) = 1-P\left(Z\leq \frac{.05-.03}{.01}\right) = 1-\Phi(2)=0.02275013$$
where we were told that $\mu = .03, \sigma = .01$, $Z$ is a standard normal distribution and $\Phi$ is standard normal cumulative distribution function.